# Flash-- Video Child won't play

Tags: flash, video, conference

Hello I have created a simple p2p conference tool, but I have 1 major problem. I can send the stream, I know I receive the stream( I can hear the sound) but the Video will not play. I don't know why. Below is the code related to the video

```
private function initconnect():void{
                //test with UiElement
                myvideo = new Video(320,240);
                myvideo.x = 10;
                myvideo.y = 50;
                var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uic.addChild(myvideo);
                addElement(uic);


                othervideo = new Video(320,240);
                othervideo.x = 10;
                othervideo.y = 310;
                var uic2:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uic2.addChild(myvideo);
                addElement(uic2);
```

myvideo can be seen on the screen. But when I go to receive the video I get nothing.

```
public function receive():void{
                recvid = new NetStream(netconn,farpeerid);
                recvid.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler);
                recvid.play("cam");
                othervideo.attachNetStream(recvid);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
uic2.addChild(othervideo);
```

Notice the argument.

Comment: fu** lol thank you. I feel so stupid. I had reached a dead end here